# Theoretical Basics of Lambda Functions

Tags: language-agnostic, lambda

I was just wondering where I could find some language-agnostic tutorials for what lambda functions are, what their use is, and rough equivalents in languages that don't support them.

I would especially love any information on common notations.

Thanks! Please let me know if I can elaborate on this at all.

EDIT: Oh hey I forgot something.

Just in terms of terminology, what's the difference between a lambda expression or function, an anonymous/delegate function, and a closure?

Comment: How deep do you want to get into the mathematics? How "CS" should the answer be?

Comment: Mathematics? *bemused face!* By all means feel free to mention those, though I admit I'm more interested in their practical CS applications.

Comment: "practical" and "CS" in the same sentence! LOL!

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I misunderstood you. I thought when you said "CS" you meant, more practical than pure mathematics. I keep forgetting that many people see the CS as only the theoretical side. I am more interested in the "software development" side... Is that better? But any answers will be welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just in terms of terminology, what's the difference between a lambda expression or function, an anonymous/delegate function, and a closure?

Regarding terminology:

- A *lambda expression* is the original way of writing an anonymous function invented by Alonzo Church for the lambda calculus.  In the lambda calculus, all functions are pure: there are never any side effects.

  The lambda expression was adopted by McCarthy for LISP as `(lambda (arguments ...) body)`, which is spelled "lambda".  Sussman and Steele later made the semantics more faithful to Church's original.  The expression was also adopted by Haskell as `\ arguments ... -> body`, and the backslash intended to *look* like a lambda, but the Haskell committee used a right arrow instead of a dot because they wanted the dot for function composition.  The expression was adopted by Robin Milner for ML but is spelled even more strangely: `fn args => body`.  All these expressions are properly called lambda expressions, and all represent anonymous functions.  Only in Haskell are the functions pure; Lisp, ML, and Scheme all permit `body` to have side effects.
- A *closure* is what you get when you *evaluate* a lambda expression or other kind of nested function.  The closure contains not just the compiled code for the lambda expression but also information about the free variables.  (In Lisp and Scheme, the closure stores the *locations* of the free variables; in Haskell and ML, the closure stores the *values* of the free variables.)
- An *anonymous function* is a more general concept and need not be restricted to a simple binding and body.  For example, in Smalltalk a "block" represents an anonymous function, but the body of a block is a sequence of statements, so it is definitely not the same as a lambda expression.

I'm afraid I can't help you with "delegate function;" in my world, that term is used to describe something else entirely.

Comment: So to make sure I've got it understood, lambda expressions are a specific notation for representing a subset of anonymous functions... specifically, those that are just expressions with no side-effects, or else single statements, or...? (As you can see, I'm trying to figure out what the subset actually is; care to give me a nudge?)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: I've edited my answer to help clarify.  In the lambda world the body of a function is always an expression, but depending on the language, the evaluation of an expression may or may not have side  effects.  And in all the languages I mention (including Smalltalk) there's no syntactic distinction between statements and expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Asking for a language-agnostic treatment is a very severe restriction.  I can recommend a couple of tutorials on the lambda calculus:

- A [tutorial by R. Rojas](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf) focuses on getting quickly to the point of programming with lambda calculus.
- A [tutorial by Prakash Panangden](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs152/readings/prakash.ps.gz) goes into a little more technical depth and ends by showing how you can simulate recursion using a fixed-point combinator.

If you want to understand the use of lambda and higher-order functions in *programming*, I think you are better off abandoning your agnosticism.  A great paper for the ML/Hope/Miranda/Haskell family of languages is

- [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.html) by John Hughes.  Hughes will show you some interesting use cases of higher-order functions and in general will do a good job helping you understand why people are interested in all this lambda stuff in the first place.

Comment: I apologize if language-agnostic is too restrictive... As I said in the comments to the question, really any answers will be welcome. I'm just trying to gain a general understanding, though, and I had figured (perhaps incorrectly) that pure notation would be the way to go. On the other hand, it might be possible that a specific language example might be a better place to start, and that I can try to inductively infer the general theory from there... I'm only asking the question here; I trust you all to help me by answering it how you like.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to be referred to Alonzo Church's lambda calculus.

By far the most common notation for lambda functions is LISP.

Abelson & Sussman "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" is probably the most accessible text that covers the subject, along with applications.

If you want to see where it started, dig out McCarthy's ["Recursive Functions of Symbolic Expressions and Their Computation By Machine, Part I"](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html).

Comment: SICP should be required reading for anyone doing software development. Lisp/Scheme may not end up being the language you use later on in life but what you learn from it is highly valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Learn a dialect of Lisp (Scheme is currently quite popular). In fact I afree with John's recommendation to read "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" and learn Lisp along the way.

Lisp started out not as a programming language but a mathematical notation to describe computing. It was designed as something better to teach students than Turing machines (and if you've ever worked on a Turing machine you'd know how much they suck). The fact that Lisp code can be compiled and executed was an accident. The fact that Lisp is very close to lambda calculus (which was a different branch of mathematics) was also an accident (it was proven only much later after the language was designed).

Most of Lisp's abilities were not really "designed" into the language, not the same way as other language copying Lisp. They emerge out of the few simple rules Lisp was based on - just like theorems in math emerge out of the rules numbers are based on.

Comment: I remember having to write a Turing machine simulator once. That was not fun, although I was proud of how I had managed to create a partial brain**** interpreter as an example for verifying that the simulator worked. I think it had over a hundred different states.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get too far into Lambda calculus without running into the related [SKI combinator calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), so you might as well dip your toe into that and get it over with.  The delightful and strange [To Disect a Mockingbird](http://dkeenan.com/Lambda/index.htm) is, if not the best place to start, possibly the oddest.  Your brain will feel like it's being rewired by an alien.  Really.

Some crazy person implemented a language for the SKI calc.  Here's an [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/) program to print the Fibonacci numbers:

````
```s``s``sii`ki
  `k.*``s``s`ks
 ``s`k`s`ks``s``s`ks``s`k`s`kr``s`k`sikk
  `k``s`ksk
````

Hey, don't blame me.  I didn't invent it.

Things got even stranger when it was shown that a [Perl regular expression in a loop could implement the SKI calculus](http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=print;node_id=809842), and therefore, that Perl regular expression in a loop is Turing complete.

Comment: ::wince:: I've read some of those... my head hurts. I'll have to come back to this. Interesting stuff so far, though, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Wikipedia page on Lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) yet?  It's heavier on math theory but eventually does get to more practical issues once you hit [first class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#First-class_functions).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'd skimmed that page in the past, but armed with some of the other information this question has generated, I was able to understand it better this time around.